# Can a marriage proceed if fiancé is unconscious?

Tags: catholicism, marriage

On the morning he was to be married an elderly man is stricken by a massive stroke. His elderly fiancé is devastated.

He lies in a coma unresponsive with no hope of recovery.

Not withstanding the legalities of the concept in various countries, does the Catholic Church permit a marriage to be performed so that his fiancé can fulfill his wish to marry and there by also be given legal status as his wife and eventual heir?

Comment: There are medical procedures  and/or medication  to deal with that!

Comment: @KenGraham Actually they can: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11083604/

Comment: @curiousdannii Still a question of consent is needed!

Comment: Hey @KenGraham  I’m looking for an answer and you seem to have one.

Comment: I could but the question needs rephrasing.

Comment: I’ll work on it.

Comment: @KenGraham Doesn't the fact that the wedding was to take place that very morning constitute consent.

Comment: @MikeBorden  Marriages Ceremonies are generally done in the afternoon. The question of  Josephine marriage is the rarest of the rarest of situations and are generally guided by a prudent confessor.

Comment: @Ken "Josephine marriage"? What's that?

Comment: @curiousdannii [Josephite marriage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephite_marriage). Even in this scenario consent must be proven.

Comment: Regardless of whether the church permits it or not, the laws of most Western countries would render it illegal and therefore null and void. In Europe in particular, [only marriage consent exchanged before the state is considered legally binding in most countries](https://www.ncronline.org/news/world/european-countries-distinguish-between-religious-civil-marriages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, marriage in the Catholic Church is not a sacrament ministered by a priest. It is rather a sacrament ministered by the couple. Each minister of the sacrament needs to state their consent. The priest is simply the official witness. ([source](https://www.quora.com/Who-is-the-minister-for-the-sacrament-of-marriage-and-how-does-the-sacrament-take-place?share=1))

The Catechism of the Catholic Church [states](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c3a7.htm):

> Section III. Matrimonial consent. "The Church holds the exchange of consent between the spouses to be the indispensable element that "makes the marriage." If consent is lacking there is no marriage." CCC 1626

Since the fiance is unconscious, he cannot be a co-minister in the sacrament, and therefore cannot get married at that point in time.

Comment: Can we get a more official source than Quora?

Comment: @Kris Catechism of the Catholic Church. https://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c3a7.htm Section III. Matrimonial consent. "The Church holds the exchange of consent between the spouses to be the indispensable element that "makes the marriage." If consent is lacking there is no marriage."

Comment: Cool so edit that resource into your answer.  Thanks

Comment: @Kris Added. ...

Comment: @AnthonyBurg How does the Catholic Church define consent in this scenario?

Comment: @agarza "The consent consists in a "human act by which the partners mutually give themselves to each other": "I take you to be my wife" - "I take you to be my husband." This consent that binds the spouses to each other finds its fulfillment in the two "becoming one flesh." The consent must be an act of the will of each of the contracting parties, free of coercion or grave external fear. No human power can substitute for this consent. If this freedom is lacking the marriage is invalid." Ibid. So it's a clear expression of consent by an act of the will of each of the persons to be married.